# Is it possible to find the values for $z^0$ and $0^z$ at $z=0$ ($z \in \mathbb{C}$) “objectively” using contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose $f(z) = z^0$ and $g(z) = 0$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$

When $z \ne 0$ we have $f(z) = 1$ And $g(z) = 0$

When $z = 0$ the values of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ is of indeterminate or undefined.

In such a case, can one find the contour integral on a circle, say $|z| = \epsilon$ And use the value of integral or use the residue theorem to find the values of $f(0)$ and $g(0)$? Or because the continuity of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ could be in question (not knowing for sure what the value of $f(0)$ will not make this method rigorous?

I found the answer of this question in discussion about Riemann’s theorem about removable singularity. Probably because this question is currently on hold I cannot add an answer. Therefore I will answer it here.

Riemann Singularity Theorem essentially states that when a function is holomorphic and bounded everywhere in a small punctured disk around $z=z_0$ Except at $z_0$ then such singularity can be removed and the function can be treated as holomorphic at $z=z_0$. In the case of $f(z) = z^0$, $f(0) = 1$ and in case of $g(z)=0^z$, $g(0) = 0$. Thus when it comes to removable singularity, the value at the indeterminate point can be determined by the limit and it is not left as a “subjective” choice! Thus it is not a matter of whether we “want” it to be holomorphic when it comes to removable singularity of a complex function. (However for real functions it is probably subjective).

I am speculating that the convention $0^0 = 1$ may be coming from the observation that most continuous functions we deal with are nonzero and when they are raised to $0$ They will resolve to $1$. (Examples: $z^z, sin(z)^z$, etc)

BTW, there are two other types of singularities:

If $z=z_0$ is a pole, then the function is unbounded in the disk near $z=z_0$, and we cannot use the above theorem.

If there is an essential singularity at $z=z_0$, then a path can be found for ANY complex value one desires as $z$ approaches $z_0$!!!

Singularities are explained very nicely by Prof. Steven J Miller in a lecture available on the YouTube [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FEAPeT0-3EY)

Comment: "Indeterminate form" is most commonly used about limits, not concrete expressions. Deciding that $0^0=1$ is the most unproblematic convention.

Comment: @Arthur I’ve heard that although most number theorists accept this convention, other mathematicians aren’t sold on it. E.g. See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MMpJv5K5h9w

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that in this specific case, blackpenredpen's attitude to $0^0$ (not the limit, but the exact value) is the wrong attitude. Why, when we first encounter it, $3^{-2}$ is also undefined ("What does it mean to multiply $3$ by itself $-2$ times?"), as is $5^\pi$. But then we _expand_ the definition of exponents so that the two expressions get a value. The exact same thing can be done to $0^0$. It is undefined until we expand the definition of exponents accordingly. And defining $0^0 = 1$ is the best choice.

Comment: $0^0$ is the number of maps from the empty set to the empty set, so fits perfectly with the most basic definition of power

Comment: You don't need to 'find' $0^0$. Its value is a convention.

Comment: @Arthur i hear what you are saying. However in case of $3^{-2}$, we are lucky, because we can say it is $\frac{3^1}{3^3}$. With functions such as $0^z, z^0, \sin(z)^0, \sin(z)^z, (z^2)^z, z^{(z^2)}$ I suspect we may get different answers if we want these functions to be continuous (I.e follow some order like $3^{-2}$ follows)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "I want $f:z \mapsto z^0$ to be a holomorphic function", then your argument with the contour integral (as well as the continuity argument) shows that  "$0^0 = 1$" is the only possible definition in order for $f$ to be as you require.

Comment: It makes sense. Hypothetically speaking, let us say we find two functions $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ which are holomorphic at $z=0$ such that $g(z) + h(z) = f(z)$, then it would not be the question of “what I want”, but “what is”. Right?

Comment: I don't think I understand, why do you consider two functions? One would be enough. But in order for that to mean that $f(0) = 1$, It is in fact a matter of "what you want", because if you do not require $f$ to be holomorphic you can define $f(0)$ to be *anything*.